# How to Configure Kafka Connector to Use SASL_SSL Security Protocol With SASL/SCRAM connection in Mule 4

Tags: apache-kafka, mule, kafka-consumer-api, mulesoft, mule4

I am trying to integrate Mule application with Kafka using SASL-SSL-Security-protocol (SCRAM-SHA-512). But I don`t see where to pass this SASL-SSL parameter, the only part I can set it is where the TLS config is but I`m not using TLS

```
<kafka:consumer-config name="Apache_Kafka_Consumer_configuration" doc:name="Apache Kafka Consumer configuration" doc:id="38a5a50b-516f-4d3f-88b3-cf6fe2d45b94" >
        <kafka:consumer-sasl-scram-connection groupId="test-dvs" username="username" password="password" encryptionType="SCRAM_SHA_512" endpointIdentificationAlgorithm="disabled">
            <tls:context enabledProtocols="SASL_SSL" />
            <kafka:bootstrap-servers >
                <kafka:bootstrap-server value="bootstrapservername:9096" />
            </kafka:bootstrap-servers>
            <kafka:topic-patterns />
        </kafka:consumer-sasl-scram-connection>
    </kafka:consumer-config>
```